# Bixby: Login facility

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I want login system in my capsule so that i can provide user more recommendation based on their profile of interest. So far, neither I am able to find any document related to login facility nor any example. It would be appreciated if will get any document or example.

Answer (score 0):

Bixby supports logging in through OAuth 2.0, and this is the best way to guide your users through a login flow.

You will need to provide your own service to handle this OAuth flow, as Bixby Developer Center does not offer any web hosting services.

https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/actions.using-oauth

Comment: Will it draw UI or do I need to code it out and how?

Comment: It'll do the login step for you, UI logic and all. You can try this sample capsule, which has a mock OAuth component. https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/sample-capsules/walkthroughs/simple-transactional

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciated

Comment: Also is there a possibility that user can user can use app as a guest user if no login credentials?

Comment: I have tried the sample and as per the document i have done the changes to sample and it is working good... but what I couldn't understand is after login how it is redirecting to bixby app. I mean once i will authorise the user from my endpoint, what should i return to redirect it to the bixby. what is the use of `token-endpoint` and how does it affect the authorisation.

Comment: I need to understand the asked concept in the comment... Please reply

Comment: Please ask a new question if you need a reply, as that's the best way to get a spotlight on your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

> Also is there a possibility that user can user can use app as a guest
>   user if no login credentials?

When you define your endpoints, you can define Actions that require OAuth and other Actions that do not require OAuth and the latter ones will define the "guest user" flow that is capable within your capsule prior to logging in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... Also could you please look at my query into the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need all the features of OAuth, and only need to store a few things between sessions with the same user, you may use the [$vivContext.bixbyUserId](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/capsule.permissions.bixby-user-id-access) value as an anonymous, but unique identifier for a user, and store their preferences using that id as a key, in a 3rd party database that you maintain.

I've done this with the "My Brain" capsule, to store quick memories/notes for users, without any requirement that they login or establish an account. I've created a [tutorial version of the My Brain capsule](https://github.com/vboughner/bixby-capsule-with-aws) that outlines the steps you need to use AWS for this purpose. Please feel free to clone or fork it and customize it for your needs.